# I am having overflow problems when I used bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap-4

I coded a law firm website template and I made use of bootstrap but there is this vast space on the right when I finished. There’s a scroll bar which allows scrolling to the left and I can’t seemed to get rid of it. Below is the a link to the site. I would really appreciate if anyone could help me. I actually coded the site all over again but still couldn’t get what was wrong

[http://warisandsons.ultihost.net/![enter](http://warisandsons.ultihost.net/!%5Benter) image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yefvj.jpg)

Comment: I just checked the site and everything looks okay. Can you share a picture of what you mean?

Comment: I just did that please

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

I added the code below and it works

```
html, body{
    Width: 100%
    Margin: 0;
    Padding: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden
}
```

Thanks to everyone